# Source code of Python module that I installed from the web

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, python-3.7

How am I supposed to view the source code of a third party python module (pywhatkit) that I installed (using pip).
I also tried using the open() and read() functions, but it didn't work and the output shows.

> Err: file not found

Comment: In your python terminal, if you first import the module `import pywhatkit` then on the command line type just the name `pywhatkit` it should show you the path where the module is installed. You can then just navigate to that path in your OS and read all the .py files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python library source code often is stored in github.
In this case the source code you want you can find here:
https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/awesomepy/blob/master/program.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like Pycharm, you can ctrl-click on that module name in your code and it will take you to the file with the definition. Normally, the installed modules are found in lib/site-packages/ of your python installation directory.

Comment: Yes but it only shows the info , call functions and documentations , Not the source code.